# All tests are running automatically after rebuilding the Coded UI project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

All tests are running automatically after rebuilding the Coded UI project in Visual Studio, I dont want to run all the tests soon after rebuild the project

Comment: I don't think this is a c# question. You should have better luck adding in `visual studio` or `coded-ui-tests` tags. I can't write any c# code to fix your problem, it likely has to do with visual studio settings or settings specific to "coded ui projects".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got the solution but, there is run option to select run all the tests after build In Visual studio Test tab. this is being enabled for some reason. so i unselected the option resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, Go to Test->Test Settings and unselect the "Run Tests After Build" Menu item. That will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply